# React-router: Passing data to component via route

Tags: json, react-router, reactjs

I generate the routing of my app with the help of a data object which contains information about the routes, the desired path (slug), the according  component and eventually sub-routes (nestedRoutes). If a route has nested routes I would like to pass them to the component as a data object and use them in the component e.g. for a sidebar navigation.

The routing is working fine, but I don’t get the data `nestedRoutes={route.nestedRoutes}` passed to the component.

If you like please take a look at my code snippet:

```
var data = {

  "routes": [
    {
      "title": "MLS Styleguide",
      "slug": "/mls-styleguide",
      "component": MLSStyleguide,
      "nestedRoutes": [
        {
          "title": "Basic Typography",
          "slug": "/mls-styleguide",
          "component": Typography,
          "isIndexRoute": true
        },
        {
          "title": "Form & Fields",
          "slug": "/mls-styleguide/forms-fields",
          "component": FormsFields
        },
        {
          "title": "Form Sections",
          "slug": "/mls-styleguide/form-sections",
          "component": FormSections
        },
        {
          "title": "Filters",
          "slug": "/mls-styleguide/filters",
          "component": Filters
        },
        {
          "title": "Side Panels & Containers",
          "slug": "/mls-styleguide/side-panels-containers",
          "component": SidePanelsContainers
        },
        {
          "title": "Tiles & Content",
          "slug": "/mls-styleguide/tiles-content",
          "component": TilesContent
        },
        {
          "title": "Tooltips & Notifications",
          "slug": "/mls-styleguide/tooltips-notifications",
          "component": TooltipsNotifications
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Playground",
      "slug": "/playground",
      "component": Playground
    }
  ]
}



module.exports = (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>

    {data.routes.map(
      function(route) {
        if (route.nestedRoutes) {
          return (
            <Route path={route.slug} nestedRoutes={route.nestedRoutes} key={route.title} component={route.component}>

              {route.nestedRoutes.map(
                function(nestedRoute) {

                  if (nestedRoute.isIndexRoute) {
                    return (
                      <IndexRoute  key={nestedRoute.title} component={nestedRoute.component}/>
                    )
                  } else {
                    // {console.log(nestedRoute.slug)}
                    return (
                      <Route path={nestedRoute.slug} key={route.title} component={nestedRoute.component}/>
                    )
                  }
                }
              )}
            </Route>
          )
        } else {
          // console.log(route.slug)
          return <Route path={route.slug} foo="bar" key={route.title} component={route.component}/>
        }
      }
    )}
  </Route>
)
```

Any comment or hint in the right direction is welcome, thanks!

**EDIT**

Code of the receiving component.
Please don’t wonder! The links data in the `getInitialState()` function serves as a workaround at the moment. When the component actually receives the `this.props.nestedRoutes` this will be removed.

I hope you get the idea!

```
export default React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return {
      links: [
        {
          "title": "Basic Typography",
          "slug": "/mls-styleguide/"
        },
        {
          "title": "Form & Fields",
          "slug": "/mls-styleguide/forms-fields"
        },
        {
          "title": "Form Sections",
          "slug": "/mls-styleguide/form-sections"
        },
        {
          "title": "Filters",
          "slug": "/mls-styleguide/filters"
        },
        {
          "title": "Side Panels & Containers",
          "slug": "/mls-styleguide/side-panels-containers"
        },
        {
          "title": "Tiles & Content",
          "slug": "/mls-styleguide/tiles-content"
        },
        {
          "title": "Tooltips & Notifications",
          "slug": "/mls-styleguide/tooltips-notifications"
        },
      ]
    }
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Sidebar className="left">
          <SideNavbar links={this.state.links}/>
          {/*<SideNavbar links={this.props.nestedRoutes}/>*/}
        </Sidebar>
        <div className="content-container">
          {console.log(this.props.nestedRoutes)}
          <h2>MLS Styleguide</h2>

            {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: So your  if (route.nestedRoutes) passes successfully, but when creating Route component, nestedRoutes prop is undefined?

Comment: Right, @Maggie! When I try ```{console.log(this.props.nestedRoutes)}``` in the particular component, I get an ```undefined``` :(

Comment: Can you post the code for the Route component?

Comment: Updated with component code, thanks for your attention!

Comment: Why should `react-router` pass props to your components? You can pass parameters in route like so: `<Route path={nestedRoute.slug + '/:' + someParameter} key={route.title} component={nestedRoute.component}/>` and you will be able to retrieve this parameter in `this.props.params.someParameter` inside component. Is this the thing you wan't to achieve or i'm getting it wrong?

Comment: @Syberic: I think you’ve got me wrong. Passing the data into the path doesn’t make any sense to me. Can I even pass an object through params?

Comment: @PDXIII okay then the first workaround i see is passing component as `<Component yourProp={prop}>` istead of `Component`

Comment: @Syberic sorry I don’t understand what you mean. But I solved the problem otherwise (see Answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I am not able to understand the provided solutions.

But I found a workaround: I just took the data, put it in a separate file and imported it in both files. It serves the purpose, it is simple and it is done.

Thank you all for your support!

Comment: "nobody knows a way to solve the problem by passing the data object via the route to the component. ". It's untrue. I just showed you the way to pass your own props to components in the comments to question.

Comment: I don’t want to insult you, so I updated my answer. But sorry, I really don’t understand your advice.